# [PCL_tutorial] No tf data.Fixed Frame camera_depth_frame does not exist

Tags: ros, rviz, fixed-frame, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed this tutorial 4.1 (http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials) and ran these with kinect v2

$ rosrun my_pcl_tutorial example input:=/narrow_stereo_textured/points2

$ rosrun rviz rviz

After that I selected  camera_depth_frame for the Fixed Frame  and select output for the PointCloud2 topic.
But I could not see anything and rviz said "No tf data.Fixed Frame camera_depth_frame does not exist"

How can I get downsampled images? thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237852/%5Bpcl_tutorial%5D-no-tf-data.fixed-frame-camera_depth_frame-does-not-exist/) by [student_ja](https://answers.ros.org/users/27259/student_ja/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not gone through the tutorials bt can you run rosrun tf view_frames command and see if Frame camera_depth_frame exists in the tf tree. If not then your program is not able to publish the tf data.

---

Originally posted by [sar1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/25409/sar1994/) with karma: 46 on 2016-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0